# PHPUnit Selenium. Is it possible to run tests twice before actually marking the test as failed when running it as a test suite?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I run my test suite/script every week, and it seems like some test cases always fail even though there isn't any bugs.

When I check the failed test cases the next day, about 2/3 of them are fine and passes.

I already increased the timeout to 60 seconds

I'm pretty sure the reason why the test case failed is because it sometimes take awhile for a page to load or upload a file which causes the WaitFor timeout.

Is it possible to run tests twice before actually marking the test as failed when running it as a test suite?

Comment: instead of using vanilla phpunit, you'll have to create your own custom test runner method.  `if (testFails) { runItAgain() while maxTries != 3}`

Answer (score 1):

If your tests fail sometimes not because of a bug, the real solution would be to try to narrow down *why* your test pass sometimes, and sometimes not. If your suspicions about a long page load turn out to be true, instead of trying to rerun the test again - which would artificially prolong test execution time without providing any definitive test result since it could fail again, you should try one of the following:

- **Settle on a comfortable timeout** (after checking how long an average page load/file upload takes), and treat any timeout as a real failure rather than indefinitely retrying again.
- **Discard the test.** A test that does not produce reliable results is worse than no test, because there is the danger that you may come to distrust/dismiss the test results in general.
- **Separate the test into a different suite**, a group of tests that have external dependencies and may fail due to external reasons beyond your control/code. This will give you the confidence of tests that can be run to ensure your code doesn't break anything, and another group of tests for complete coverage of your application.

Comment: I'd like to stress the fact that partially failing tests are worse than no tests. Find the reason for failure and eliminate it. If that means to refresh some caches by initially fetching some pages before starting the real test, this might be an option as well.